# Does int * & has any real sense?

Tags: c++, function

I'm looking few exercise from university about C++ and I found out this exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int& f(int*&);
int& f(int*& x) {
    *x = 5;
    return *x;
}
int main() { 
    int y = 1, x; 
    int* z = &y; 
    x= f(z);
    cout << y << " " << x <<endl; 
}
```

I was wondering: does `<any type>*&` has any real sense? Isn't `f(int*& x)` the same as `f(int x)`? Aren't you passing the pointer to the L-value of the variable?

Comment: IMO it would be clearer if it was written as `int* &x`. That way you can easily see which what the type and name is.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, maybe that's what I was getting wrong. Is the first "operator" always associated with the type and the second always associated to the var? If I declare `int&*x` would that be `int& *x`?

Comment: Also, you should note that in your example there is no point it the prototype declaration. A prototype is only need if the function is defined after it's first use.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, XCode was giving me a notice error for that. Then in the prototype I should define `int& f(int*);`? EDIT: No I tried it, it doesn't work like that. :( I think I'm more confused now...

Comment: Ok, maybe I was wrong. Thats what I've always thought though.

Comment: IMHO, Bjarne shouldn't have reused the address-of operator as a reference declarator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `int* &x` you are passing the same pointer(by reference). Otherwise with only `int* x` you are passing a copy of the pointer and then you can't change the original one in the function. `&x` makes `x` an alias of the original parameter.

Comment: Oh so the `&` isn't related to the type? It's `int* &x` and not `int*& x`?

Comment: You can write it both ways. The role of the `&` here is to make an alias of the parameter. You are working with the same thing, just with a different name.

Comment: And yes, it is more logical to write `int* &x`, than `int*& x`. Because with the `&` you are making an alias of the passed parameter, not of the type.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli - Imagine a swap function. An easy way to write it is this: `void swap(int &x, int &y) { int t = x; x = y; y = t; }` The essential thing here is that the `&` makes it that you are working with the original variables.

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever between `int*&x`, `int*& x`, `int* &x`, `int *&x`, `int* & x`, `int *& x`, `int * &x` and `int * & x`.

Comment: @FredOverflow - Yes, that's correct. At least for me the most logical choice is - `int* &x`.

Comment: Ok. I think I got this. But when you do `void f(int* x);` and you declare `int* y = &randomVar;` and you call `f(y);` aren't you passing the address of `randomVar` to the function which is an alias of `y` anyway?

Comment: `int* y = &randomVar;` `y` is not an alias of `randomVar`. `y` only points to `randomVar`(`y` is a pointer). When you put `&` in a function parameter you are not making a pointer - you are making an alias - you are working with the SAME variable, just with a different name.

Comment: Passing the address of `randomVar` (and thus being able to change its contents) and passing `y` by reference (and thus being able to make `y` point somewhere else) are two different things.

Answer (score 8):

`f(int*& x)` is not the same as `f(int x)`. In the first case `x` is a reference to an integer pointer whereas in the second case `x` is just an integer.

Lets start from the basics:

When you write `f(int &x)` means that `x` is a reference to an integer and you can change the value of `x` in the function and the change will be reflected in the calling function.

Similarly, when you write `f(int*& x)`, it means that `x` is reference to an integer pointer and when you change the address that x points to, the change will also be reflected in the calling function.

Answer (score 4):

It's a reference to a pointer to an `int`. The function is then able to change the pointer if it wants to. In your example it doesn't make sense, but it obviously does have a use.

Answer (score 3):

nope: `*&` here doesn't mean "dereference addressof". It means: "pass a pointer byref".

Answer (score 3):

```
int& f(int*& x) {
    *x = 5;            // note: changes the pointee, not the pointer
    return *x;
}
```

In this example, you don't gain anything by passing the pointer by reference, since you're not changing the pointer. Passing a pointer by reference is only needed when you intend to change the pointer:

```
void f(int*& x) {
    x = new int(42);   // note: changes the pointer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing sybols when they are used as operators or declarators.

If you use * when declaring variable, that means veriable is a pointer. When you use * as operator, that is dereference operator.

```
int *& name
```

simply means you are taking ***pointer to int by reference.*** **The * and & do not cancel each other out.**

If you had line of code like this:

```
var = *& var2;
```

then yes, it would be same as:

```
var = var2;
```

Comment: References are *not* identical to pointers. They are conceptually related, but there are several important differences.

Comment: It's not exactly the same; it can be *used similarly* to int**; but int ** requires that the extra level of indirection is dealt with explicitly: so in the example above, the caller would have to pass f(&z) instead of f(z), and the assignment in the body would be **x=5, not *x=5.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a quick answer.